# Creating "pie slice" in OpenSCAD?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, openscad

When making a cylinder, sometimes I need to only take a pie slice. I'm currently using [this](http://forum.openscad.org/Creating-pie-pizza-slice-shape-need-a-dynamic-length-array-tp3148p3149.html) neat trick to make pie slices for angles under 90 degrees. However, I have need of a few angles over 90 but under 180 degrees. Is there a way to generalize/extend this to work for these bigger angles?

```
module pie_slice(r=3.0,a=30) {     
   intersection() {
    circle(r=r);
    square(r);
    rotate(a-90) square(r);  
  } 
}

pie_slice(r=10,a=15);
```

Comment: I think the easiest would be to use `difference`. Circle minus two cubes with sides 2*R. (Or one of size 2*R and one of size R.)

Comment: IIUC, this is similar to my current workaround (I've posted below for reference). I use `union` instead of `intersection`. Unfortunately, you have to examine how many degrees the caller wants and use one or the other - I have yet to find a universal method

Comment: Think of it this way: you have two rectangles that cover each half of the circle. Then you open a gap between them of the angle. That should work for any angle between 0 and 180.

Comment: Oh snap, that sounds perfect. I'll give it a try, thanks

Comment: Or use a module that can make pie slices, e.g. [Chamfers-for-OpenSCAD](https://github.com/SebiTimeWaster/Chamfers-for-OpenSCAD).

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use:

```
module pieSlice(a, r, h){
  // a:angle, r:radius, h:height
  rotate_extrude(angle=a) square([r,h]);
}
pieSlice(110,20,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

My current workaround is to use `union` instead of intersection. Unfortunately, that means I have to use an `if` clause which makes the code have two paths instead of one clean approach. Also, unlike the above method, this does not result in a clean cylindrical shape but must instead by combined with a proper cylinder to get the final pie slice

```
   size = length + 2;
    if (angle_deg <= 90) {
      translate([0,0,-1]) 
      intersection() {
        cube(size);
        rotate(angle_deg-90) cube(size);
      }
    } else if (angle_deg <= 180) {
      translate([0,0,-1]) 
      union() {
        cube(size);
        rotate(angle_deg-90) cube(size);
      }      
    } else {
      echo(str("FAILURE - Angle cannot exceed 180"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although generating complex shapes by combining primitive OpenSCAD shapes is a well-established tradition, and is often all that is needed, it would be more elegant in this case to generate a pie slice directly using the `polygon` function and a list comprehension.

```
module pie_slice(r=3.0, a=30) {
  polygon(points=[
    [0, 0],
    for(theta=0; theta<a; theta=theta+$fa)
      [r*cos(theta), r*sin(theta)],
    [r*cos(a), r*sin(a)]
  ]);
}
```

Note that the above code is a little crude, since it does no error checking, but it works. It uses the `$fa` special variable for the step angle.